# How to set AWS region using docker compose up with ECS context

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I'm using the new docker compose ECS integration to create an ecs context for deploying as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/). I selected during `docker context create ecs my-context` for it to use an existing AWS profile which has `us-west-2` configured as its default region. However, `docker compose up` always results in it deploying to `us-east-1`. I tried exporting `DEFAULT_AWS_REGION` but that didn't work either. Is there a way to set the region in the context? It looks like the older `docker ecs setup` command asked for the region but that cmd is now deprecated.

Comment: same problem here, need to launch on a different region. were you able to overcome @stowns?

Comment: I have the same problem too

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix this via the AWS CLI directly.

```sh
aws configure set default.region eu-central-1
```

Source: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/configure/set.html

Comment: You are a lifesaver. This helped me when getting InvalidVpcID.NotFound. I even checked that the region was correct in the AWS CLI, but docker compose must be running through another profile under the hood